# Expression not printing to page with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm a AngularJS newbie. I have to learn it to help maintain an existing site. I made a simple angularjs app to just print hello but it is not working. What is wrong with my code. Thank you.
Codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/pozRNqN?editors=1010

html

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
  {{test}}
</div>
```

angularjs code

```
var app = andgular.module('testApp', [])

app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'hello'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`andgular` in your js code is a typo. Just replace with `angular`.

Comment: Oh man. Embarrassing. Hope my score doesn't go too low. Thank you Feyyaz.